# Stability of RNA including Thymine nucleobase

Tags: rna, nucleic-acids, nucleotide

Does an RNA double strand containing the nucleobase T instead of U has a lower free energy?

Or more precisely: There are tabulated values for the change in free energy of the canonical neighboring base pairs [here](https://rna.urmc.rochester.edu/NNDB/turner04/index.html).
Do you know of any source where values for neighboring base pairs of e.g. GT/CA got compared to GU/CA?

Comment: I think you mean bond energies.

Comment: If you want you can call "free energy of neighboring base pairs" the bond energy. But I think it is less precise.

Comment: I was under the impression that you could only measure free energy changes, not free energy. And presumably bond energies would be equivalent to the free energy changes in breaking a hydrogen bond. But my chemistry is a little rusty, so do point me to sources that measure actual free energies of base pairs of any sort.

Comment: Ah no, you are right! It is change in free energy. I adapt my question.

Comment: I think my problem with bond energy is that the change in free energy is not simply the breakage of hydrogen bonds. It is an interplay between stacking (pi-pi) and hydrogen bonding.

Comment: But the stacking would depend on the neighbouring bases. There have been lots of studies in this area, but It’s not my field. Naively I would think a rT-rA bond would have a similar energy to a rU-rA bond. But do many actually occur? I would think most rT bases are in tRNA where the T is generally in a loop and has to be generated by enzymatic modification.

Comment: I would also guess rT-rA is similar to rU-rA. I don't know if rT-rA is frequently occurring. But I am not a biologist. I would like to know that more concerning prebiotic evolution.

Comment: I don’t know because I wasn’t there, but the current thinking is that thymine arose late. There is no rTTP, only dTTP. I have an answer somewhere about thymine and the RNA World hypothesis, and discuss the biochemistry. As I said, the only place I know rT occurs naturally is as a modified base in tRNA and I don’t think it’s in base-paired stem but I would need to check that.

Comment: When you say there is no rTTP you mean there is no rTTP found in current biological systems, right? I mean you can probably make it somehow in a chemistry lab.

Comment: You certainly could. But my arguments relate to the evolution of biochemical pathways. I think if you want to take this further you need to tell us what your hypothesis is, or spend some time combing through the literature of synthetic nucleic acid duplexes.

Comment: I think my question is clear though.